# Open intent in empty parent on expendable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

What i have is an expendable list view and i have some of it's parent don't have childs , and i want on these group click listener , but my app keep failing because of **NULL pointer Exception** , and i know that this happens because it has no childs , so how can i handle it?
 Here is my code which i tried :
expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(myListGroupClicked);

```
    }
private OnGroupClickListener myListGroupClicked =  new OnGroupClickListener() {

      public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, long id) {

       //get the group header
    long click=id;
       //display it or do something with it
       Intent i=new Intent(Activity.this,seconed.class);
       startActivity(i);
       return false;
      }

     };
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Cosider switching to java 8. it has a null pointer exception optional feature.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html